# Linux difference between when to use parentheses

Tags: linux, bash

Why do I get extra empty line when running 2). To me 1 is like 2. So why the extra line in 2)?

1)

```
export p1=$(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd)
#                                  ^
echo p1
```

2)

```
export p2=$(cd $(dirname $0)) && pwd
#                           ^
echo p2
```

Comment: Using backticks is discouraged. Use $(...) instead, you can nest it easily and it is more easy to read. In a code block, it should be available though.

Comment: because cd does not print anything on stdout.

Comment: Did you intend to echo `$p1` and `$p2`?  The fundamental difference is whether the output of `pwd` is captured in the variable or not.  As to blank lines, it is like because `$(…)` removes trailing newlines (if not white space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$echo $0
/bin/bash
$ echo $(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd)
/bin
$ echo $(cd $(dirname $0)) && pwd

/home/user
$
```

In the 1st expression it becomes `echo $(cd /bin && pwd)`. Therefore the inner 2 commands execute in a subshell and return back the `pwd` value which is then echoed.

In the 2nd expression it gets reduced to `echo $(cd /bin) && pwd`. Therefore only the cd command executes in a subshell and returns nothing to echo (hence by default echo just prints an empty line). Since echo ran successfully(exit code=0) `&&` results in true and `pwd` cmd is run in current shell and `pwd` gets printed

Answer (score 0):

p1 captures the output of `cd` (empty) and `pwd`.

p2 only captures the output of `cd`, and then runs `pwd` without redirection.

---

`echo p1` prints a literal `p1` (with a newline).  I guess you didn't actually copy-paste from your terminal, but instead typed in some thing else.

---

```
peter@tesla:~$ export p2=$(true) && pwd
/home/peter
peter@tesla:~$ echo "x${p2}x"
xx
```

`cd` in a subshell doesn't affect the parent shell's pwd, so I just substituted the `true` command to make it more readable.